# Subscriber database to publisher database

Tags: replication, publish-subscribe

If the publisher side of a transactional replication database goes down along with its backups for some reason, how would
I go about making the subscriber database as a publisher again with minimal impact and time.

As I understand at this point in time, the subscriber database comes loaded with triggers and views that are
needed for replication

TIA
Gopal

Comment: along with its backups? Ooops!

Comment: "how would I go about making the subscriber database as a publisher again with minimal impact and time." - Hire an expert, would be my advice...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: you can't easily.

You need expert help (especially since you have no backups), not just the (albeit good) answers you might receive here.